# What's wrong with my python selection sort?

Tags: python, indexing

I can't figure out why the python program produces the following output:

```
c:\Python Programs>selection_sort.py

[7, 4, 2, 9, 6]

[2, 4, 7, 9, 6]
[2, 6, 7, 9, 4]
[2, 6, 4, 9, 7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Python Programs\Python Practice\selection_sort.py", line 11, in <modu
le>
    num_list[i], num_list[min_num] = num_list[min_num], num_list[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

c:\Python Programs>
```

I think I understand the list index out of range part, but I'm not sure about why the 6 becomes the second element when i = 1.  Didn't the machine read my if statement?

Here is the code below:

```
num_list = [7,4,2,9,6]
len_num_list = len(num_list)
print num_list
print""#print empty string to separate the original list from the following iterations 
for i in range(0,len_num_list):
    min_num = min(num_list[i:]) #finds minimum number in list to the right of i
    if min_num>num_list[i]:
        min_num = num_list[i]
    num_list[i], num_list[min_num] = num_list[min_num], num_list[i]
    print num_list
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's note that in your snippet:

```
min_num = min(num_list[i:]) #finds minimum number in list to the right of i
if min_num>num_list[i]:
    min_num = num_list[i]
```

the `if` will **never, ever** match -- since `min_num` is the minimum of a sub-list that starts with `num_list[i]`, it can't possibly, ever, under any circumstance, be greater than the latter.

So, lose the last two of these three statements -- they're about as useful as checking `if 2+2 != 4:`:-).

Next, let's note that you don't really want `min_num` to be a **value** (which is what your call to `min` gives you) -- you want it to be an **index** into the list, in order to perform the swap:

```
num_list[i], num_list[min_num] = num_list[min_num], num_list[i]
```

But trying to turn a value into an index via the `index` method is quite an iffy path: if the input list can have any duplicates, `index` will always locate the first one of them, and that might quite possibly tangle you up.  I personally would choose not to go there.

Rather consider the more direct path of finding the minimum **index** using the corresponding **value** via the `key=` feature of `min`!  I.e:

```
for i in range(0,len_num_list):
    min_ind = min(range(i, len_num_list),
                  key=lambda j: num_list[j])
    num_list[i], num_list[min_ind] = num_list[min_ind], num_list[i]
    print num_list
```

If you're not familiar with the `key=` feature of many Python built-ins (`min`, `max`, `sorted`, ...), it's really a good thing to learn.

It sorts (or gives the min, or max, or) a certain sequence, with the comparisons done after passing each item of the sequence through the "key extraction function" you pass as `key=`.  Here, you want "the index of the minimum" and you get that by picking the min index with a `key=` of the corresponding look-up of each index into the list.

I personally dislike lambda and might use `key=numlist.__getitem__`, but that's not very readable either -- most readable is always to use `def` (and I'd do the same for that swap functionality), e.g...:

```
def item_in_list(index): return num_list[index]
def swap(i, j): num_list[i], num_list[j] = num_list[j], num_list[i]
for i in range(0,len_num_list):
    min_ind = min(range(i, len_num_list), key=item_in_list)
    swap(i, min_ind)
    print num_list
```

which I find to be the most readable and elegant approach to this task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `min(num_list[i:])` returns a number from the list, not an index into that list.  You can use the `index` method to get the index corresponding to `min(num_list[i:])`.   Thus, try:

```
num_list = [7,4,2,9,6]
len_num_list = len(num_list)
print num_list
print""#print empty string to separate the original list from the following iterations_
for i in range(0,len_num_list):
    min_num = min(num_list[i:]) #finds minimum number in list to the right of i
    j = num_list.index(min_num)
    if min_num>num_list[i]:
        min_num = num_list[i]
    num_list[i], num_list[j] = num_list[j], num_list[i]
    print num_list
```

This produces the output:

```
[7, 4, 2, 9, 6]

[2, 4, 7, 9, 6]
[2, 4, 7, 9, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 9, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```